# find submatrix with a given sum

Tags: algorithm, matrix, complexity-theory

Just encountered a programming problem which is to find a subarray in a given array (non-negative elements only) that adds up to a particular value K and runs in O(n) time. Fortunately, I've found a solution (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum/), however, I am curious how should I apply this idea to a 2D matrix. In other words how do we find a submatrix in a given matrix (no negative elements as well) that adds up to a number K without enumerating all the possible submatrices?